# Apple "Badger" SceneKit demo- how is the kart animation generated?

Tags: ios, scenekit

In an effort to learn Swift SceneKit, I am studying the Apple ["Badger"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Badger/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017309-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) demo. It features a kart animation following railroad tracks. I do not understand what is generating this animation. There is a scene.scn file which has a "Bob root" node that is a placeholder for the kart animation, and there are numerous animation .scn files that have the "Bob root" with no animation. I understand that "let cartAnimation = scene.rootNode.animation(forKey: cartAnimationName)!" applies the animation to this Bob root node such that it follows the tracks.

But what is generating this animation- how is the kart following the tracks? There is no node in scene.scn with this motion, and I don't see  being described programmatically anywhere. Sorry, not entirely a coding question but I need to understand this to move forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Animations were designed in a 3D software, then exported as Collada, imported in Xcode and archived in the .scn files. The sample code simply retrieve these animations and trigger them when needed.

Comment: Thanks! but I am more specifically interested in how that cart animation was generated- is it a keyframed animation that came in with the scene.scn file or is it generated programmatically on the fly? I can't find any animated cart nodes in the base scene.scn file, only a placeholder node, and the character animation files only contain animations for the character. I wish the .dae files hadn't been converted to .scn files, because with a .dae file in Xcode you can see the animations explicitly listed in the scene graph...

Comment: hi @Galaxy61 an animator simply manually "moved the cart" along the tracks, that's all there is to it.  note however that almost all modeling software (Maya, etc) has UTILITIES to make it easier to do that, you know?

Answer (score 0):

The specific anime in question is nothing more than a manual anime of the object following a certain path, which, "just happens" to be the same as the apparent visual track. There's nothing more to it.

---

If you're curious about "simulating" this (so, there's actual logic involved), it's very commonplace.

With everyday game engines (so, Unity etc) this is so common that there are systems in place for it.

The usual approach is that you just make a spline curve which is the shape in 3D of the track, road or whatever.

Then you have some code that makes a point, follow, that spline curve, moving a certain distance each time unit. You can see it's easy from there.

(There are a few details, you can see that, you need a normal and tangent to the spline at any point, to know which way the train, dragon, whatever, should be oriented at any time, as well as position.)

And of course then to generate the actual "road", "track" or whatever ...

you can see that you also do THAT automatically, following that same spline curve.

(You often call that process a "loft".)

(Aside, I actually did one of the earliest tools to automate this, and made quite a bit of $ from it! Like anything in software it's now easy.)

If you glance on for example the unity "asset store" there are innumerable "spline tools" (all of the spline tools include "tracking along the spline," which is indeed the main purpose of a spline) and "loft" tools.  (I think "megashapes" is or was the popular one; you can watch the videos etc. of the various "loft" tools, for, much more info on what you're asking about.)